# Find the area of a segment of a circle, given radius and central angle.

Tags: geometry

> Find the Area of a segment of a circle if the central angle of the segment is $105^\circ$ degrees and the radius is $70$.
>
> [image]

Formulas I have:

- Area of a non-right angle triangle= $\frac{1}{2}a b \sin C$.
- Area of segment = ( area of sector ) $-$ (area of triangle).

Please, could you explain it step by step so I can understand, thanks

Comment: Subtract from the area of a circle sector the area of a triangle.

Comment: Which part of the Question do you already understand?  For example, do you know the area of the entire circle? Can you find the area of the circular sector subtended by the $105^\circ$ ?

Answer (score 4):

You can work out the area of the sector then subtract the area of the triangle.

The area of a sector is given by $\frac{1}{2}r^2\theta$ if $\theta$ is in radians or $\frac{1}{2}r^2\pi\frac{\theta}{180^\circ}$ if $\theta$ is in degrees.

The area of the triangle is give by $\frac{1}{2}r^2\sin\theta$.

Combining these two gives: $\frac{1}{2}\times70^2\times\pi\times\frac{105^\circ}{180^\circ}-\frac{1}{2}\times70^2\times\sin105^\circ \approx 2123.34$

Answer (score 2):

Formulas that you need to know:-

(1) The area formula for $\triangle ABC$ $[A = \dfrac 12 ab \sin C]$. (Edited.)

(2) The area of a sector (OAB) formula $[A = \dfrac 12 r^2 \theta]$; where $\theta$ is the central angle and it should be in radian instead of degree.

Added. The conversion formula is $[\pi$ radians $= 180^0]$.

---

Additional info: The common naming convention and the derivation of the area formula:-

We already know that $[⊿ABC] = \dfrac {1}{2}b \times h$.

[image]

Since $h = a \sin C$, then $[⊿ABC] = \dfrac {1}{2}ab \times \sin C$.

Comment: I think you need a $\pi$ and some degree normalization in the (2). And (perhaps a little picky) $1/2$ is better than $0.5$ in these formulas.

Comment: @EthanBolker Fixed.

Comment: thanks for the formula for the area of the sector could you please explain to me for the triangle formula what would A B C be?

Comment: @user437353 The area formula for a triangle can be used when two of the sides (i. e. “a” & “b”) and the included angle (i. e. $\angle C$) are known. In your case, a = b = 70 = the radius and $\angle C = \angle O = 105^0$. Then, area of $\triangle O..= \dfrac 12 (70)(70) \sin 105^0$.

Comment: @user437353 See also the added portion.

Comment: Nice job, with the answer, @Mick, and your involvement with the OP in comments.

Comment: @Mick:  I deleted the comments I made below your post, except for my last comment, to help get rid of the "noise".  So you might want to do the same, with comments to me.  By all means, keep the thread with the OP!  Cheers!

Comment: @amWhy Done....

Answer (score 1):

Forget about particular values
and name the things to be measured.

Call the radius of the circle
$r$
and the angle subtended
by the sector $t$.

The area of the part of the circle
containing the sector
and internal triangle
is
$tr^2/2$.

The internal triangle
has altitude
$r\cos(t/2)$
and base
$2r\sin(t/2)$,
so its area is

$\begin{array}\\
(1/2)(2r\sin(t/2))(r\cos(t/2))
&=r^2(\sin(t/2)\cos(t/2))\\
&=r^2\sin(t)/2\\
\end{array}
$

since
$\sin(t)
=2\sin(t/2)\cos(t/2)
$.

The area of the sector
is the difference 
of these expressions,
which is
$tr^2/2-r^2\sin(t)/2
=r^2(t-\sin(t))/2
$.

Now you can substitute
the values of the radius
and angle of the sector.

As a check,
for $t = \pi$,
this gives
$\pi r^2/2$,
which is area of
the semicircle.